# Issues pointing openshift url to a namecheap managed domain CNAME record

Tags: dns, openshift, cname

I just registered a .io domain name with namecheap.com and have a RoR app hosted on openshift.  When I create a CNAME record for www to point to my openshift app at myawesomeapp.rhcloud.com, namecheap adds a "." after the openshift url.  This causes wrong translation as the request is redirected to **myawesomeapp.rhcloud.com.** and openshift sees it as different from **myawesomeapp.rhcloud.com**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "." after a url is the correct CNAME convention.  However, it depends on how the http server is configured to correctly translate a given url.  In my case, openshift sees app.domain.com and app.domain.com. as different URLs and tries to forward request for the latter to a different web server.  For obvious reasons, it can't find one and throws a 404.

If you've domain registered with namecheap and you come across a similar problem, use the URL-frame (url cloaking) record instead of a CNAME record.  URL-frame works same as url redirect except it doesn't change the url in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

DNS deals with names of hosts and zones/domains. DNS doesn't know about URLs. Web servers know about URLs.
The main task of a name server is to look up a name, and return its associated ip address. They don't redirect.
Even if you use a CNAME record, at the end there will be an ip address. The intermediate name the CNAME record resolved to, is not carried over from web client to web server in its request. Therefore, your web server won't see the trailing dot as result of the nameserver producing it. Your problem is caused by something else.

Comment: I know the problem mate, just wasn't sure about a workaround.  The problem is with how openshift configured their records. e.g.: www.heroku.com and www.heroku.com. translate to different urls and you'll get a 500 for the latter.  try pinging them from a console and you'll see both resolve to the same IP.  amazon on the other hand translates both urls correctly.

Comment: your question is tagged DNS, and you decribe your CNAME records as problem source, because your DNS hoster doing something to the record. Both names you mention resolve to the same set of ip addresses. Are you surprised that I gave a reply pertaining to DNS when you tagged your question as such?

Comment: I was looking for a workaround when neither the DNS service provider or the hosting service would resolve the problem, saying that's how they are configured.  You merely saying "Your problem is caused by something else" didn't answer my question, makes sense?